# Did Macros have any influence over Kulgan deciding to apprentice Pug in Magician?

Tags: riftwar-cycle

In Magician, Macros had influence on Pug getting captured and enslaved on Kelewan, so that he could eventually learn the Greater Path of magic and bring it back to Midkemia.

I'm not sure if it's stated explicitly in the books or ever hinted at, but did Macros have any influence over Kulgan deciding to apprentice Pug in the first place?

As it was Macros that caused Pug's initial inability to use Lesser Path magic in order to allow him to be captured by the Tsurani, he must have had known about him before they met for the first time in person on Sorcerer's Isle, so his influence on Pug's life certainly happened quite early on.

In addition, if I remember correctly Kulgan was very hesitant about choosing Pug as an apprentice, and certainly would have been more unlikely to apprentice him if they had not previously met. Did Macros ever mention influencing that initial meeting, or influence Kulgan's decision in another way?

Comment: I wouldn't call it hesitant but I think it was more an unplanned act, from Kulgan's point of view. Once he made up his mind, he wasn't hesitant. That is how I remember it.

Comment: **(This contains a very minor spoiler but its relevant to your question and it actually doesn't ruin the plot of anything at all)*** I've recently been re-listening to the whole series on Audible, i don't think its mentioned in the first riftwar trilogy but (without spoiling too much)in the serpent war saga im sure it comes out that Macros has been involved in pugs life since like birth, or certainly before Tomas' parents took him in,  and he did have some influence on pushing him toward Kulgan at the start of Magician, i would need to actually go through the book though to find an exact quote

Comment: Do you mind pinpointing where exactly it is stated that Macros is the reason why Pug was unable to use the Lesser Path? 
I've quite recently finished reading the first trilogy again, and I do not remember such an event

Comment: @EyalMosheGreen I don't know if it's explicitly confirmed, but I think at some point Pug at least suspects it. When he gets captured and put in the prison room that restricts his use of Greater Path magic, he tries to use Lesser Path and has no trouble, despite being unable to when he was training under Kulgan. I'm not sure if he ever discusses it with Macros, but it is at least hinted at that Macros could have been the one stopping his ability to use Lesser Path magic in order to get him captured and enslaved on Kelewan in order to learn and bring the Greater Path magic back to Midkemia.

Comment: But his inability to use the Lesser Path was not the reason why he was captured and sent to Kelewan. Pug was captured during  a mission to study the enemy lines.

and on Kelewan he was "discovered" as a magic user by a Greater Path mage (forgot his name) that noticed that he was using a Lesser Path technique of calming one's mind.

Lastly, Kulgan chose Pug as an apprentice since he saw that Pug, without prior training, could use a scrying orb (happened in Kulgan's house in the woods)

Comment: @EyalMosheGreen I think that helps to confirm my point. He had a natural affinity for learning magical techniques (such as scrying and calming his mind), yet whenever he attempted Lesser Path magic he felt like something was blocking him using it. And Macros could see the future at that point, I assumed that he knew that if Pug been able to use Lesser Path magic, he could have either used it to prevent himself being captured, or could have escaped before he learned the Greater Path.

Comment: If I am not mistaken In either the second or third book either Macros or one of Milamber's friends explains that people with the affinity to the Greater Path could hardly use the Lesser Path. When Pug returns to Kelewan (After his escape and return to Midkemia) he is captured, and restrained with cuffs that block the Greater Path. At that point Pug succeeds for the first time in actually using the Lesser Path. After that he is again unable to fully use it (as far as I recall)